# Insert json into google spreadsheet

Tags: java, javascript, json, google-visualization

I have json data in this format

```
{
        "jobstatus": [
            {
                "dateAndTime": "Nov 19, 2013 12:20:00 UTC",
                "jobId": "TCC_tfc",
                "userId": "admin",
                "status": "Completed",
                "jobType": "Excel Upload"
            }
        ]
    }
```

i am trying to create google spreadsheet in google docs with this data. There can be multiple rows. So how to insert my json into created spreadsheet? Maybe I should use google docs api?

Comment: What do you mean by "google table"?

Comment: @jhanvi he talks about google spreadsheets

Comment: While am trying your code am Getting error as "TypeError: google.visualization is undefined" How can i solve that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the first think you have to do is declarate your data as JSON variable with the comand 
`var jobs = JSON.parse(x);` 
 
where x is your piece of JSON.

 I don't know if you know how to parse a JSON, but is very easy: 
`jobs.jobstatus.dateAndTime   -> gives you  "Nov 19, 2013 12:20:00 UTC"`
and so for the other fields.

 
then to fill the google table (after link the right library) as you can see in this link [Google Visualization API Reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference) you have to declarate new google table variable:

 
 var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
and fill this with your data taken from your JSON variable like:

```
    data.addRows(["datetime",jobs.jobstatus.dateAndTime],
      ['jobId', jobs.jobstatus.jobId],
      ['userId', jobs.jobstatus.userId],
      ['status', jobs.jobstatus.status],
      ['jobType', jobs.jobstatus.jobType]
  ]););
```

This will be done for each row and each columns.

Comment: While am trying your code am Getting error as "TypeError: google.visualization is undefined" How can i solve that